# sendmsg succeeds but wireshark shows multiple tcp retransmissions

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, wireshark

After around 1.5 hours of inactivity data from client was sent using sendmsg on nonblocking socket. But the packet did not reach the other end. Client side shows lots of packet retransmissions for this packet.

client and server are linux and sysctl command gives the following relevant output:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_retries1 = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
```

Server side SO_KEEPALIVE is set.

Are there any options which can be set at the client side.

Comment: If the server became unreachable in the 1.5 hours, maybe it got assigned a new dynamic IP?  Is server or client on a mobile device, by any chance?

Comment: client has static ip.